# UIModalPresentationCurrentContext and UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext different behaviour in iOS 7 and 8 respectively

Tags: ios

I want to make transparent screen so I present view controller with UIModalPresentationCurrentContext for ios7 , for ios8 I used  UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext.
Both gives transparency but in iOS 7 when I present modal view controller with **UIModalPresentationCurrentContext**  , then rotate device only modal view controller is rotated and the view under modal view controller is not rotating along with Modal.

But when I using **UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext** in ios8 then presented and presenting view controller both rotates as per device rotation.

I want to rotate both presenting view controller both rotates as per device rotation in ios7 what to do?

See below screen shots for better understanding..[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally digging a lot came to know it is not possible using **UIModalPresentationCurrentContext and UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext** unless  app is having fixed orientation.

So I Implemented **UIContainerView** and added and remove sub view as needed.

For more read apple docs having UIContainerView and see this link http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers